# Include module not working in gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have a gem called `private_lib`. 
The file `lib/private_lib.rb` contains the following:

```
require 'private_lib/version'
require 'private_lib/handicap'
require 'private_lib/traversal_cap'

module PrivateLib

end
```

The `lib/private_lib/handicap.rb` file contains the following

```
# module for handicap functions
class Handicap
  include TraversalCap
  -- other code
end
```

and the file `lib/private_lib/traversal_cap.rb` contains the following

```
module TraversalCap
  def some_method
  end
  -- other code
end
```

I also have a test file `spec/handicap_spec.rb` which contains the following

````
require "spec_helper"
describe Handicap do
  include TraversalCap
  -- some tests that access the ```Handicap``` class
  -- some tests that access directly the traversal_cap some_method.
end
````

When I run `rspec spec/handicap_spec`, I get the following error

```
private_lib/lib/private_lib/handicap.rb:3:in `<class:Handicap>': uninitialized constant Handicap::TraversalCap (NameError)
    from private_lib/lib/private_lib/handicap.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Why isn't the handicap class seeing the traversal_cap module?

Comment: Hi @Obromios
It's because you required `traversal_cap` below `handicap` but you included traversal_cap inside handicap so that it couldn't find this module. 
Solution is you should do like this:
`require 'private_lib/version'
require 'private_lib/traversal_cap'
require 'private_lib/handicap'

module PrivateLib

end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the order you require the files.

At the time the line `require 'private_lib/handicap'` is run it reads the `handicap.rb` file and hits the line where you `include TraversalCap`. But you haven't yet run `require 'private_lib/traversal_cap'` at this point so the module is undefined.

Quick fix is to change the order of the `require` calls, or alternatively put `require 'private_lib/traversal_cap'` at the top of the handicap file.

Comment: Thats works, I am used to using ruby on rails which has autoloading.